# How to assign a css class to a radio-button group in a radio button list?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net, css

I am trying to validate a radionbutton assign a css. Since it is a server control i can only assign one way but when i checked using jquery it is actually attaching that class to the table not the radio group.

here is my code

```
      <asp:RadioButtonList CssClass="required"  ID="rdb_studysubj"  runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="rdb_studysubj_SelectedIndexChanged">
                            <asp:ListItem  Value="Humans">Humans</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Value="Non-Human primates">Non-Human primates</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Value="Rodents">Rodents</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Value="Others">Others</asp:ListItem>
                        </asp:RadioButtonList>
```

when i use this jquery to validate it says invalid

```
       function WebForm_OnSubmit() {
      if($('.required').val()==null) {              
         $("#validation_dialog").dialog({
             title: "Validation Error!",
             modal: true,
             resizable: false,
             buttons: {
                 Close: function () {
                     $(this).dialog('close');
                 }
             }
         });
         return false;
     }
     return true;
 }
```

because the css class is attached to the table no to the radio button group which holds the value. how can we fix this

Answer (score 0):

Using the child selector *input* should be able to tell if it's value is null:

```
if ($('.required input').val() == null) {
```

However, I assume you want to check if only one of the radio buttons has been selected? If that's true, I believe the conditional statement you want is:

```
if ($('.required input:checked').length > 0) {
```

Comment: it looks like it works for a single radiobutton list...how do i check for mutliple controls, like radiobuttonlist, checkboxlist,listbox. I am assigning the css class required to all these controls and try to validate that way....any ideas

Comment: It should work on every RadioButtonList control with the class `.required` applied to it. As for other controls, the `:checked` selector works for checkboxes, radio buttons, and select elements. Reference: http://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/

Comment: You may need to alter your conditional statement to use a foreach loop to validate against multiple controls: https://api.jquery.com/each/

Comment: I tried this but not able to do a foreach loop for all controls any ideas                                                                                             
         if (($('.required input:checked').val() == null)) {
                     
                         alert("Hello");
                     if ($(this).is(':enabled')) {
                         names[$(this).attr('name')] = true;
                     }
                     }